# DatagridView-click - when cell value to dbnull it ignores further changes

Tags: datagridview, dbnull

I have this code to change cell value (on click) in DataGridView (all cells are ether X or empty(DBNull)).

```
        If IsDBNull(DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value) Then
        DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = "X"
    ElseIf DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = "X" Then
        DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = DBNull.Value
    End If
```

Everything works fine, except when cell from X is turned to DBnull, that cell stays empty and ignores further clicks on it. Also when cell is empty, click changes it value to "X", and on another click it changes to blank, after that no more changes of that cell value is possible.

If some1 could help me fix this code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a perfect solution but I fixed it like this:

```
            If IsDBNull(DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value) Then
            DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = "X"
        ElseIf DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = "X" Then
            DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = " "
        ElseIf DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = " " Then
            DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = "X"
        End If
```